# Availability of a Pioneer2AT model

Tags: gazebo-model

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,
Any chance of the Pioneer2AT model hitting the model database?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1519/availability-of-a-pioneer2at-model/) by [logicalguy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24/logicalguy/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 73 on 2013-02-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm working on a Pioneer 3AT model right now, which should be good 'nuff for you. :)

I'm working on the ROS plugin right now which should be the last thing I need to finish before I publish it.

Here's a preview:
https://bitbucket.org/dawonn/gazebo_models/overview

My model is named pioneer3at, and you'll probably want to comment out the plugin line at the bottom of the sdf.

---

Originally posted by [dereck](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/219/dereck/) with karma: 86 on 2013-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [logicalguy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24/logicalguy/) on 2013-03-04**:
Hi, really excited about your post.  Thanks!  Looking forward to testing it.  I'm using gazebo standalone and will be using it with player, so ROS is not really necessary for me.  All the best!

**Comment by [dereck](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/219/dereck/) on 2013-03-04**:
That's actually good to hear, because I'm spending some extra effort to make the plugin generic so that it works with both player and ROS. :) I added a link to the full model I'm working on. Just remove the plugin line from the bottom of the sdf and you should be set. :)

**Comment by [logicalguy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24/logicalguy/) on 2013-03-05**:
Hi, I'm testing it just now, and two issues:

1. The uri in the model.sdf are wrong.  They are not model://Pioneer/meshes etc. but model://pioneer3at/meshes...
2. When I insert the pioneer in my heightmap terrain world it starts moving and I can't get it to stop.  But when I insert it in an empty world it sits quietly.

**Comment by [dereck](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/219/dereck/) on 2013-03-05**:
It seems that I forgot to move the model back to my repository from the working directory.... :P As for the other problem, the robot has no forces acting on the joints by default, so it will probably roll into a valley by default.

**Comment by [logicalguy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24/logicalguy/) on 2013-03-06**:
Thanks a lot, bro, really appreciate all your effort that we're benefiting from :)

**Comment by [dereck](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/219/dereck/) on 2013-03-06**:
You may also benefit from the plugin I'm writing for it. I'm using gazebo topics for the plugin, so it should work with Player. http://pastebin.com/mVpCcRhz http://pastebin.com/cvEyxTp9

**Comment by [logicalguy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24/logicalguy/) on 2013-03-13**:
So what is the status as of now?  I just looked at the bitbucket site and it says the plugin is going to be merged with official gazebo models?  Any idea when this will happen?

**Comment by [dereck](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/219/dereck/) on 2013-03-13**:
Well, I'll give the maintainer an e-mail and see if he'll pull it.

**Comment by [logicalguy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24/logicalguy/) on 2013-03-14**:
Just an idea - I've renamed the model name in the model.sdf file to pioneer3at rather than Pioneer3AT, just to make it consistent with the name of the pioneer2dx model.  What do you think?

**Comment by [dereck](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/219/dereck/) on 2013-03-14**:
probably a good idea